# Given a set of points in $R^2$, how can I quickly determine if there exists a pair of distinct points that are within a fixed distance?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Given $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, I would like to quickly determine if there exists of a pair of distinct points $p,q \in \{p_i\}$ such that $|p-q|<r_0$, where $r_0>0$ is fixed. One way is to iterate through every distinct pair and check the pairwise distance. However, I was curious if there exists a faster way. I believe the method I described is $O(n^2)$. Is it possible to get something better?

Comment: What do you mean by quickly?

Comment: @Chickenmancer Faster than O(n^2). I edited my question.

Comment: What are the relations between $p,q$ and all the $p_i$? Because as of now there are none.

Comment: @NoelLundström Correct. There are no relations between p and q, other than they must not coincide.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you don't impose any conditions on the $p$ and $q$ that are related to the $p_i$, currently just choosing $p=(0,0)$ and $q = (0,r_0/2)$ gives an algorithm that is $O(1)$ and satisfies the requirements in your post. I'm assuming you meant to include something in this post which makes my solution not valid. Do you mean that $p$ and $q$ have to be in the set $\{p_i \}$?

Comment: @NoelLundström Of course $p,q \in \{p_i\}$. I shall edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of the [closest pair of points problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem).  A solution to that problem can solve your problem:  after finding the closest pair of points, $\{p,q\}$ return the boolean $(|p-q|<r_0)$.  The planar closest pair of points problem can be solved in $O(n \log n)$ time by a variety of methods.  There are a number of implementations out there.  [Here's one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-onlogn-implementation/) at GeeksforGeeks.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently the closed pair problem was one of the earlier problems in computational geometry. Very neat!